# Merge 2 JSON objects from 2 files using jq

Tags: merge, jq

I have two json files
1.json

```
{
  "outputs": {
     "item1": {
       "name": "name1",
       "email": "email1"
     }
  }
}
```

2.json

```
{
  "outputs": {
     "item2": {
       "name": "name2",
       "email": "email2"
     }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to merge them using jq

```
jq -s '{
      "Items" :
      {
            "list" : .[] | .outputs ,
      },
  }' 1.json 2.json
```

and I get just two Items objects, but I want to have one Items object and all item* merged like this

```
{
  "Items": {
    "objects": {
      "item1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "email": "email1"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "email": "email2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried `.[0] * .[1]` trick, but I cannot put it into object construction.
How can do this with jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `add`ing the `--slurp`ed array:

```bash
jq -s '{Items: {objects: map(.outputs) | add}}' 1.json 2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FpBGluG8P2u)

Another approach could be using `reduce` with `inputs` and the `-n` flag:

```bash
jq -n 'reduce inputs.outputs as $i ({}; .Items.objects += $i)' 1.json 2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8PTo77X-xeq)

Output:

```json
{
  "Items": {
    "objects": {
      "item1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "email": "email1"
      },
      "item2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "email": "email2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```